# Node JS express - updating a single document

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

i cant figure why my documents are not updating.

I fetch any record and load it into the form with http://localhost:3000/update2?buyerID=2299. However when i change a field and click submit, the field doesn't update when i redirect to the route which lists all the documents. Its just the same as before.

Can anyone see where im going wrong?

http://prntscr.com/dj49wd - the form

**get**

```
router.get('/update2', function(req, res) {
        var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

        if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
            res.render('error', {message: "You need to enter a buyerID to update a specific order", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
        } else {

            mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB",error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
                } else {
                    var WishList = db.collection('orders');
                    WishList.findOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, function(err, result) {
                        if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
                            res.render('error', {message: "Failed to find order",error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
                        } else {
                            console.log("get results", result)
                            res.render('updateOrder2', {qs: result});
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**post**

```
    router.post('/update2', function(req, res) {
        if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
            res.render('error', {message: "Failed to update order make sure the ID is current", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
        } else {

            mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB", error:{status:"", stack: ""}});
                } else {
                    var WishList = db.collection('orders');
                    var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

                    var u2Order = {
                        buyerID: req.body.buyerID,
                        name: {
                            f: req.body.f,
                            s: req.body.s
                        },
                        address: {
                            HouseNum: req.body.HouseNum,
                            streetName:req.body.streetName,
                            town:req.body.town,
                            postCode: req.body.postCode
                        },
                        deliveryInfo: [{delivId: req.body.delivId,
                            serviceName: req.body.serviceName,
                            postTime: req.body.postTime,
                            delivCost: req.body.delivCost,
                            pickUp: req.body.pickUp}],

                        gender: req.body.gender,
                        student: req.body.student,
                        pName: req.body.pName,
                        purchaseDate: req.body.purchaseDate,
                        price: req.body.price,
                        sName: req.body.sName

                    };
                    console.log("Updating..", u2Order)
                    WishList.updateOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, {$set: u2Order}, function (err, result){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("Cannot update", err)
                        } else {
                            console.log("Updated..", order)
                            res.redirect("/orders")
                        }
                    })

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**The JSON**

```
{  
      "buyerID":2447,
      "name":{  
         "f":"Jess",
         "s":"Thompson"
      },
      "gender":"Female",
      "birthDate":"1987-02-02",
      "student":false,
      "appOS":"Android",
      "address":{  
         "HouseNum":"22",
         "streetName":"Coolford Road",
         "town":"Sedley",
         "postCode":"DY3 9CK"
      },
      "productID":2382,
      "pName":"Macbook Pro",
      "type":"Laptop",
      "purchaseDate" : "2016-11-30", 
      "releaseDate":"2016-03-11",
      "provider":"Apple",
      "starRating":3,
      "available":true,
      "About":"2.9GHz dual-core Intel Core i5 processor, Turbo Boost up to 3.3GHz",
      "sellerID":2245,
      "sName":"Amazon.co.uk",
      "price":1700.33,
      "discount":false,
      "deliveryInfo":[  
         {  
            "delivId":2382,
            "serviceName":"UPS",
            "postTime":"1 Day",
            "delivCost":"£7.50",
        "pickUp": false
         },
         {  
            "delivId":2383,
            "serviceName":"Royal Mail",
            "postTime":"2-5 Days",
            "delivCost":"free",
            "pickUp": false
         },
         {  
            "delivId":2384,
            "serviceName":"UPS",
            "postTime":"1 Week",
            "delivCost":"free",
            "pickUp": true

         }
      ]
   }
```

**updateOrder2.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Recipe</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>
<body>

<form name= "updateOrder" action="/updateOrder" method="POST">
    User ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="buyerID" value = "<%=qs.buyerID%>"><br>
    <b><p>Nested Objects (firstname and second name)</p></b>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="f" value = "<%=qs.name.f%>"/><br>
    Second Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="s" value = "<%=qs.name.s%>"/><br>
    <b><p>Nested object - customer address</p></b>
    House number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="HouseNum" value = "<%=qs.address.HouseNum%>"/><br>
    Street name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="streetName" value = "<%=qs.address.streetName%>"/><br>
    town:<br>
    <input type="text" name="town" value = "<%=qs.address.town%>"/><br>
    post code:<br>
    <input type="text" name="postCode" value = "<%=qs.address.postCode%>"/><br>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender" value = "<%=qs.gender%>"/><br>
    Student?:<br>
    <input type="text" name="student" value = "<%=qs.student%>"/><br>
    Product ID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="productID" value = "<%=qs.productID%>"/><br>
    Product Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pName" value = "<%=qs.pName%>"/><br>
    Product Type:<br>
    <input type="text" name="type" value = "<%=qs.type%>"/><br>
    Date Purchased:<br>
    <input type="text" name="purchaseDate" value = "<%=qs.purchaseDate%>"/><br>
    Product Price:<br>
    <input type="text" name="price" value = "<%=qs.price%>"/><br>
    Seller Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="sName" value = "<%=qs.sName%>"/><br>
    <b><p>Array Objects (delivery details)</p></b>
    DeliveryID:<br>
    <input type="text" name="delivID" value = "<%=qs.deliveryInfo[1].delivId%>"/><br>
    Survice Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="serviceName" value = "<%=qs.deliveryInfo[1].serviceName%>"/><br>
    Post Time:<br>
    <input type="text" name="postTime" value = "<%=qs.deliveryInfo[1].postTime%>"/><br>
    Delivery cost:<br>
    <input type="text" name="delivCost" value = "<%=qs.deliveryInfo[1].delivCost%>"/><br>
    Pickup:<br>
    <input type="text" name="pickUp" value = "<%=qs.deliveryInfo[1].pickUp%>"/><br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Mongoose or any type of ORM? Helps to know what we're dealing with.

Comment: im using express and MongoDB. Not mongoose

Comment: can you see the issue?

Comment: Can you post your updateOrder2 template/html?

Comment: Jim i posted the ejs, can you see what ive done wrong?

Comment: you gotta markModified

Comment: how is that done? thanks

Comment: findOne then update the fields, objects need to have `doc.markModified('field')` before the save .. also check out findOneAndUpdate

Comment: could you give me an example of how doc.markModified would be implemented to one of my fields in my ejs file please. I dont understand. Ill give correct answer if it works :d

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `findOne` then modify using `markModified` of object fields?

```
function async(cb) {
    WishList.findOne({id: id}, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) throw err;
        doc.buyerID = req.body.buyerID;
        doc.name = {
            f: req.body.f,
            s: req.body.s
        };
        doc.address = {
            HouseNum: req.body.HouseNum,
            streetName:req.body.streetName,
            town:req.body.town,
            postCode: req.body.postCode
        };
        doc.deliveryInfo = [{delivId: req.body.delivId,
            serviceName: req.body.serviceName,
            postTime: req.body.postTime,
            delivCost: req.body.delivCost,
            pickUp: req.body.pickUp}];

        doc.gender = req.body.gender,
        doc.student = req.body.student,
        doc.pName = req.body.pName,
        doc.purchaseDate = req.body.purchaseDate,
        doc.price = req.body.price,
        doc.sName = req.body.sName

        doc.markModified('name');
        doc.markModified('address');
        doc.markModified('deliveryInfo');

        doc.save(cb);

      };
}
```

Comment: no idea about that answer. The console.log updates it fine, i think the ejs is having problems displaying the updated data

Comment: take a look at my ejs plz

Comment: @JackWood to check your updates, you have to console.log a fetch of your doc after the update either through your app or through the Mongo console. If you find that the doc was updated, what you see could be query cacheing, however, the problem wouldn't be updating the doc.

Answer (score 0):

**is this correct?**

```
router.get('/update2', function (req, res) {
    var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

    if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
        res.render('error', {
            message: "You need to enter a buyerID to update a specific order",
            error: {status: "", stack: ""}
        });
    } else {
        var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB", error: {status: "", stack: ""}});
            } else {
                function async(cb) {
                    var WishList = db.collection('orders');
                    WishList.findOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, function (err, result) {
                        if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
                            res.render('error', {message: "Failed to find order", error: {status: "", stack: ""}});
                        } else {
                            doc.buyerID = req.body.buyerID;
                            doc.name = {
                                f: req.body.f,
                                s: req.body.s
                            };
                            doc.address = {
                                HouseNum: req.body.HouseNum,
                                streetName: req.body.streetName,
                                town: req.body.town,
                                postCode: req.body.postCode
                            };
                            doc.deliveryInfo = [{
                                delivId: req.body.delivId,
                                serviceName: req.body.serviceName,
                                postTime: req.body.postTime,
                                delivCost: req.body.delivCost,
                                pickUp: req.body.pickUp
                            }];

                            doc.gender = req.body.gender,
                                doc.student = req.body.student,
                                doc.pName = req.body.pName,
                                doc.purchaseDate = req.body.purchaseDate,
                                doc.price = req.body.price,
                                doc.sName = req.body.sName

                            doc.markModified('name');
                            doc.markModified('address');
                            doc.markModified('deliveryInfo');

                            doc.save(cb);
                            console.log("get results", result)
                            res.render('updateOrder2', {qs: result});

                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
})











router.post('/update2', function (req, res) {
    if (!buyerID || !parseInt(buyerID)) {
        res.render('error', {
            message: "Failed to update order make sure the ID is current",
            error: {status: "", stack: ""}
        });
    } else {
        var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect to MongoDB", error: {status: "", stack: ""}});
            } else {
                var WishList = db.collection('orders');
                var buyerID = req.query.buyerID;

                var u2Order = {
                    buyerID: req.body.buyerID,
                    name: {
                        f: req.body.f,
                        s: req.body.s
                    },
                    address: {
                        HouseNum: req.body.HouseNum,
                        streetName: req.body.streetName,
                        town: req.body.town,
                        postCode: req.body.postCode
                    },
                    deliveryInfo: [{
                        delivId: req.body.delivId,
                        serviceName: req.body.serviceName,
                        postTime: req.body.postTime,
                        delivCost: req.body.delivCost,
                        pickUp: req.body.pickUp
                    }],

                    gender: req.body.gender,
                    student: req.body.student,
                    pName: req.body.pName,
                    purchaseDate: req.body.purchaseDate,
                    price: req.body.price,
                    sName: req.body.sName

                };
                console.log("Updating..", u2Order)
                WishList.updateOne({"buyerID": parseInt(buyerID)}, {$set: u2Order}, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Cannot update", err)
                    } else {
                        console.log("Updated..", order)
                        res.redirect("/orders")
                    }
                })
                db.close();
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: the structure of your routes are wrong to keep opening and closing connections, just open once then work within that scope